# ASP.net MVC - IO.Compression library not recreating the folder structure in a ZIP file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, compression, zip

I have a business scenario where I should allow downloading of the encrypted folders as a ZIP file; meaning that the files within the folder and its subfolders are encrypted. As I perform server side decryption of the files it is necessary first to recreate the same folder structure in a temporary folder as well as to decrypt the files itself and save them into the corresponding folders of the temporary folder.

This part works well; the folder structure in a temporary file gets recreated as it should but the problem comes when I'm trying to create a ZIP file of a temporary folder using System.IO.Compression library.

When you open the ZIP file only the first folder of the structure is created as a folder and the rest of the folders are just being created as extensionless files.

**Folder structure as the unzipping application sees it**

[image: Folder structure as the unzipping application sees it]

**Code snippet:**

```
    //Creating temporary folder where the decrypted files will be extracted
    var tempFolderPath = _directory.CreateTemporaryFolder(rootFolderPath);
    var serverTempFolderPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(tempFolderPath);

    //Creating the folder structure
    RecursiveFolderCreate(folders, tempFolderPath);

    //Decrypting the files and recreating them in the corresponding folders
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        PrepareFile(file, folderPath, tempFolderPath);
    }

    //Creating the zip file
    string zipFileName = string.Concat(folder.Name, ".zip");
    string zipFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(rootFolderPath, zipFileName);
    string serverZipFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(zipFilePath);

    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(serverTempFolderPath, serverZipFilePath, CompressionLevel.Optimal, false);
    byte[] zipFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(serverZipFilePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

*Sorry this isn't a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet.*

Is it possible that an exception is being raised and not handled?

Per the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485721(v=vs.110).aspx/), what you are doing should work.  But it has the extra caveat as listed below:

> If a file in the directory cannot be added to the archive, the archive is left incomplete and invalid, and the method throws an IOException exception.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately, I'm not getting anything in the catch block.